# How to get the port number from struct addrinfo in unix c

Tags: c, network-programming, udp, sockets

I need to send some data to a remote server via UDP in a particular port and get receive a response from it. However, it is blocking and I do not get any response. I need to check if the addrinfo value that I get from the `getaddrinfo(SERVER_NAME, port, &hints, &servinfo)` is correct or not.

How do I get the port number from this data structure?

I know `inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s)` gives me server IP address. (I am using the method in Beej's guide.)

Answer (score 31):

You do something similar to what Beej's get_in_addr function does:

```
// get port, IPv4 or IPv6:
in_port_t get_in_port(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return (((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_port);

    return (((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_port);
}
```

Also beware of the #1 pitfall dealing with port numbers in `sockaddr_in` (or `sockaddr_in6`) structures: port numbers are always stored in **network byte order**.

That means, for example, that if you print out the result of the `get_in_port()`call above, you need to throw in a `ntohs()`:

```
printf("port is %d\n", ntohs(get_in_port((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr)));
```

Comment: this seems to work...i see that the port is correct, however i get a "Error receiving in UDP: Connection refused" when i try to get a response from the server. why would such a problem arise? i tried connected UDP

Comment: "Connection refused" typically means there is no process listening on the destination port you specified.  It may also indicate that there's a firewall preventing you from sending to that server/port.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but one could `assert(sa->sa_family==AF_INET6)` for the else case, as there's also `AF_IRDA`, `AF_BTH` (Bluetooth), `AF_IPX`, `AF_APPLETALK`, `AF_NETBIOS` and maybe other protocol families not yet invented.

Comment: if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)  shouldn't it be sin_family ? for AF_INET type of sockets ?

Comment: What is the 'p' in the part of the printf statement - (struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr ?

Comment: @SrinivasRavi referring back to the code in the original question, 'p' would be a pointer to a 'struct addrinfo' from `getaddrinfo`